# jQuery timeout inside function

Tags: jquery, timeout

Here is my code. What I am trying to do is to update news at my page using jQuery. The code works as intended - every 5 seconds it removes news from sidebar and posts 2 updates at their place. What I cannot do is to make it remove all news before posting updates. For now it appends updates and starts fading out old news at the same time. 
Anyone has ideas of how to set the proper timeout for this?

```
function updateNews()
{

    $('.newsUpdate').load('news.html .news', function ()
    {
        $('.MainNews').fadeOut(); /* timeout should happen here! */
        var start = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        var stop = start + 2;
        $(this).children('.news').slice(start, stop).css('display', 'none').attr('class', 'MainNews').insertAfter('.nav').fadeIn().children('span').remove();
        $(this).children('.news').remove();
    });
    setTimeout(updateNews, 5000);
}
updateNews();
```

HTML is pretty simple:

```
<div class='sidebar'>
    <ul class='nav'>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<article>main content of the site</article>
<div class='newsUpdate'>this created specially to upload news from news.html and manipulate them</div>
```

Comment: show the html then it would be clearer what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Are you trying to check for duplicates? If not wouldn't using `$.load()` directly into `.MainNews` achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1):

Use the fadeOut callback

```
function updateNews()
{

    $('.newsUpdate').load('news.html .news', function ()
    {
        $('.MainNews').fadeOut(1000,function(){
            //This code will be executed after the fadeOut
            var start = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
            var stop = start + 2;
            $(this).children('.news').slice(start, stop).css('display', 'none').attr('class', 'MainNews').insertAfter('.nav').fadeIn().children('span').remove();
            $(this).children('.news').remove();
        });
    });
    setTimeout(updateNews, 5000);
}

updateNews();
```

Comment: I tired this approach and for some reason it does not work. When I do this, nothing gets posted at sidebar even first 2 news.